# Why does SSRS Report Viewer loose report export settings on drill through?

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have a block of code that sets the Report Viewer to look as I would like it to.

I also restrict the report export to Excel or PDF.

The code I use is this

```
                //Restrict report export options
            FieldInfo info;
            foreach (RenderingExtension extension in viewer.ServerReport.ListRenderingExtensions())
            {
                info = extension.GetType().GetField("m_isVisible", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                if (extension.Name == "EXCELOPENXML" || extension.Name == "PDF")
                {
                    info.SetValue(extension, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    info.SetValue(extension, false);
                }
            }
```

These settings are forgotten if my report drills though to another report. (All the other settings remain unchanged)

Is this a bug with Report Viewer?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you need to call this block of code using Report as a parameter.
When you call a drill through report you are calling another report so you need to call this block of code using the properties of the drill through report. So my revised code becomes:

```
        private void ExportList(Report SR)
    {
        FieldInfo info;
        foreach (RenderingExtension extension in SR.ListRenderingExtensions())
        {
            info = extension.GetType().GetField("m_isVisible", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (extension.Name == "EXCELOPENXML" || extension.Name == "PDF")
            {
                info.SetValue(extension, true);
            }
            else
            {
                info.SetValue(extension, false);
            }
        }
    }
```